# How to properly build a SGDClassifier with both text and numerical data using FeatureUnion and Pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, pipeline

I have a features DF that looks like

| text | number |
| --- | --- |
| text1 | 0 |
| text2 | 1 |
| ... | ... |

where the `number` column is binary and the `text` column contains texts with ~2k characters in each row. The targets DF contains three classes.

```
def get_numeric_data(x):
    return [x.number.values]
def get_text_data(x):
    return [record for record in x.text.values]
transfomer_numeric = FunctionTransformer(get_numeric_data)
transformer_text = FunctionTransformer(get_text_data)
```

and when trying to fit, code below, I get the error `File "C:\fakepath\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 588, in bmat raise ValueError(msg) ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions. Got blocks[0,1].shape[0] == 98, expected 1.`. I tried to build functions `get_text_data` and `get_numerical_data` in different ways but none helped.

```
combined_clf = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion([
        ('numeric_features', Pipeline([
            ('selector', transfomer_numeric)
        ])),
        ('text_features', Pipeline([
            ('selector', transformer_text),
            ('vect', vect),
            ('tfidf', tfidf),
            ('scaler', scl),
        ]))
    ])),
    ('clf', SGDClassifier(random_state=42,
                          max_iter=int(10 ** 6 / len(X_train)), shuffle=True))
])
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(combined_clf, parameters, cv=5,n_jobs=-1)
gs_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: `ColumnTransformer` is probably the better approach here.  If you want to debug the `FeatureUnion`, please provide the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is the way you are returning the numeric values. `x.number.values` will return an array of shape `(n_samples,)` which the `FeatureUnion` object will try to combine with the result of the transformation of the text features later on. In your case, the dimension of the transformed text features is `(n_samples, 98)` which cannot be combined with the vector you get for the numeric features.

An easy fix would be to reshape the vector into a 2d array with dimensions `(n_samples, 1)` like the following:

```py
def get_numeric_data(x):
    return x.number.values.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Note that I removed the brackets surrounding the expression, as they unnecessarily wrapped the result in a list.

---

While the above will make your code run, there are still a couple of things about your code that are not quite efficient and can be improved.

First is the expression `[record for record in x.text.values]` which is redundant, as `x.text.values` would already be enough. The only difference is that the former is a `list` object, whereas the latter is a numpy `ndarray` which is usually preferred.

Second is what Ben Reiniger already stated in his comment. `FeatureUnion` is meant to perform several transformations on the same data and combine the results into a single object. However, it appears that you simply want to transform the text features separately from your numeric ones. In this case, the `ColumnTransformer` offers a much simpler and canonical way:

```py
combined_clf = Pipeline([
    ('transformer', ColumnTransformer([
        ('vectorizer', Pipeline([
            ('vect', vect),
            ('tfidf', tfidf),
            ('scaler', scl)
        ]), 'text')
    ], remainder='passthrough')),
    ('clf', SGDClassifier(random_state=42, max_iter=int(10 ** 6 / len(X_train)), shuffle=True))
])
```

What happens above is that `ColumnTransformer` only selects the text column and passes it to the pipeline of transformations, and will eventually merge it with the numeric column that was just passed through. Note that it becomes obsolete to define your own selectors as `ColumnTransformer` will take care of that by specifying the columns to be transformed by each transformer. See the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) for more information.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Just for to understand more, if I were to do some transformations on `number` column I should use `FeatureUnion` in a similar fashion?

Comment: Not sure which scenario 'similar fashion' is referring to. But in general, if you just want to apply different transformations to each column, you should go for `ColumnTransformer`. `FeatureUnion` is used if you want to concatenate results of multiple transformer objects on the same columns or data. An example for the latter is if you have a numeric feature `x1` in your original dataset and you want to have two new features in your final dataset, `scaled_x1` and `squared_x1`. They are based on the same feature but are now two separate results which you want to keep both.